# Doctrine "group by" doesn't returns all existing objects

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table with user alarms, I would like to get a list of ALL the alarms grouped by the user who created them.

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Alarm')->createQueryBuilder('a')->groupBy('a.userId');
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The problem is that I'm only getting one alarm per user instead of all the existing alarms for him.

If I remove the group by I get all the alarms.

Is there any way I can get all the alarms grouped by user? I was expecting to get and array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working just the way a `groupBy` clause should work. It picks the first `Alarm` item for each of `user`.

If you want all `Alarm` for a single User, you have to work along with `group_concat` which again doesn't come with `Doctrine`. You have to register a custom `DQL` function. [Check here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)